# JSONParser: IOException: Unable to resolve host "my host address": No address associated with hostname

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to get data from a `JSON` file that was written in a `PHP` file which was stored in my online hosting server(00webhost.com). When I run my program it says ***unknown host***. However, the address will give `JSON` formatted file.

I have all the permissions along with the internet permission in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Activity Class :

```
public class Recmain extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView lv;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    TextView uid;
    TextView name1;
    TextView email1;
    Button Btngetdata;

    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://tongue-tied- 
      papers.000webhostapp.com/data_fetch.php";

    //JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_USER = "user";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";

    JSONArray user = null;

    private List<movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private moviesadapter mAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rmain);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String m=intent.getStringExtra("data");
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mAdapter = new moviesadapter(movieList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
     LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        prepareMovieData();
    }

    private void prepareMovieData(){
        movie movie = new movie("Mad Max: Fury Road", "Action & Adventure", 
        "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }


    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(recmain.this,url,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            JSONParser sh = new JSONParser();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String url = "https://tongue-tied- 
      papers.000webhostapp.com/data_fetch.php";
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("id");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = c.getString("id");

                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), id , 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put("id", id);


                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat 
    for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        }
    }
}
```

Adapter class:

```
public class JSONParser {

    private static final String TAG = JSONParser.class.getSimpleName();

    public JSONParser() {
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) 
    url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

It says, unknown host.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the URL is not formatted correctly. I think there is a space between the two parts of the URL.

```
private static String url = "http://tongue-tied-papers.000webhostapp.com/data_fetch.php"
```

Please try with the URL above without any space between the `tied-` and `papers`. You have two separate URL declaration, one at the beginning of the class and the other is in the `doInBackground` method. Please try changing both.

Comment: when i am using this link, i can access the json formatted data from server through web.but in android studio it is actually not connecting with server. i think it need some more code segments.in android studio it says cant find the address at the same time when i browse for this address on web it gives correct output.

Comment: That's what I was pointed out. From the code that you posted above, the URL looks malformed (having a space in the middle). You need to get rid of the malformed URL first as suggested in my answer. Did you try looking into that? Please let me know if that does not work.